# join 2 files and print each line even if they don't match

Tags: linux

I'm sure this is super simple but I can't think of a way to do it. 
I have File1 and File2 (below) and I need to join based off the letter in the alphabet, but also print out the lines that have no match.

File1:

```
a james
b mike
c joe
d john
e nick
f chris
```

File 2

```
a 10 20 30 40
b 11 12 13 14
d 20 30 40 50
f 15 16 17 18
```

I want the output file to say

```
a james 10 20 30 40
b mike 11 12 13 14
c joe
d john 20 30 40 50
e nick
f chris 15 16 17 18
```

I'm supposed to use one line only. I tried:

```
join file1 file2 > file3
```

but that didn't print the lines that don't have a match.

Comment: Stackoverflow is ment for programming related questions, Use unix/linux stack exchange for this type of question

Comment: apologies, I didn't realize. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: No problem, Also if that answer helped you, Accept it so other people viewing this page know that its the right one

Answer (score 0):

If you do `join -a1 file1 file2 > file3` that will work because it makes it a left outer join. `join` on its own is an inner join.